# Trouble with ObservableCollection not Updating my UI with each change

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I know there's already a few of these types of questions already. But my example seems a bit different. Also, WPF and ObservableCollections are still very new to me. So help would be appreciated. My Grid is getting updated, but only after it iterates through all the "listOfFiles". I would like it to update the grid after each file it finds.

NOTE: I'm only using the Thread.Sleep to make the process more visible

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnAdd_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgFiles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="417"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class FilesFound
        {
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string FileCount { get; set; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FilesFound> file = new ObservableCollection<FilesFound>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgFiles.ItemsSource = file;
            file.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ObservableCollection<FilesFound> obsSender = sender as ObservableCollection<FilesFound>;
            NotifyCollectionChangedAction action = e.Action;
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TEST\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var file in listOfFiles)
            {
                if (file.Contains("CLIENT"))
                {
                    count++;
                    FilesFound f = new FilesFound();
                    f.FileName = file;
                    f.FileCount = count.ToString();
                    this.file.Add(f);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `foreach` loop runs in the UI thread and blocks it until it's finished. Calling `Thread.Sleep()` makes it even worse. Take a look at [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) or [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are performing this operation in UI thread. That means UI does not have any chance to update until that operation completes.

Comment: I thought using ObservableCollections alleviated this.

Comment: How should an ObservableCollection make your loop async? ObservableCollection has nothing to do with parallelism and asynchonous operations, it just notifies about collection changes.

Comment: Oh. Is what I'm looking to do possible then if I add Asynch/Await to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute the loop on a background thread but update the databound ObservableCollection on the UI thread as a single thread cannot do two things simultaneously.

The easiest way to start a background thread is to use a Task. You could then use the dispatcher to marshal any calls that access the ObservableCollection back to the UI thread. Try this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string[] listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TEST\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var file in listOfFiles)
        {
            if (file.Contains("CLIENT"))
            {
                count++;
                FilesFound f = new FilesFound();
                f.FileName = file;
                f.FileCount = count.ToString();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.file.Add(f)));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment on the post, using async/await should free up the UI thread (this is the method I have used previously - anyway).

So you need something like:

```
    private async void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TEST\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (var file in listOfFiles)
                {
                    if (file.Contains("CLIENT"))
                    {
                        count++;
                        FilesFound f = new FilesFound();
                        f.FileName = file;
                        f.FileCount = count.ToString();
                        this.file.Add(f);
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

As a side note, you should probably look up using MVVM and the ICommand interface to separate your UI and business logic.